# Calculating Euler Characteristic of Closed Subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, projective-schemes

Suppose $X$ is a projective k-scheme of dimension at least one. I want to know how to compute $\chi(X,\mathscr{O}_X(-d))$, the Euler characteristic. My idea was to use the short exact sequence $0 \to J_X \to \mathscr{O} \to \mathscr{O}_X \to 0$ where $\mathscr{O}$ is the structure sheaf on projective space and $J_X$ is the sheaf of ideals of X in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$.  But now I don't really know anything about the sheaf of ideals, so using the additivity of short exact sequences doesn't get me anywhere. Can anyone give me a hint on this problem?

Comment: If you do not know anything about $X$, then you do not know anything about its Euler characteristic, no?

Comment: that's what I thought too. The problem is coming in Vakil 18.6.k, proving Bezout's theorem using sheaf cohomology. I want to show that if $X$ is an arbitrary projective scheme and $H$ a hypersurface then $deg(X \cap H) =deg(X)deg(H)$. I have shown this if $X$ is a hypersurface, but I run into this problem in the general case.

Comment: In that situation it is not so much that you need to compute something about X than relate the result to something else, which is quite different.

Comment: Okay, maybe I am approaching the problem wrong. Can I have a hint as to what the something else is? adapting my current proof for hypersurfaces seems to not work

Comment: There is an exact sequence $0\to\mathcal O_X(-d)\to\mathcal O_X\to\mathcal O_{X\cap H}\to 0$. One must also assume that the equation of $H$ is not a zero divisor on $X$.

Comment: Hi @danneks, this short exact sequence is exactly why I asked my question above. I get here and find that $\chi(X,\mathscr{O}_{X \cap H}) = \chi(X,\mathscr{O}_X) - \chi(X, \mathscr{O}_X(-d))$, and I do not know how to calculate the last terms for an arbitrary projective scheme X

Comment: You need to find the highest coefficient of Hibert polynomial, not the Euler characteristic (i.e. the value of polynomial at 0). Use the additivity of Hilbert polynomials and that you know the highest coefficient of the Hilbert polynomial of X.

Comment: Thank you of course it was just an easy computation...sorry for the stupid question.